# Determine if $f(x) = \sqrt{|x_1x_2|}$ is differentiable at the origin.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, $$f(x) = \sqrt{|x_1x_2|}.$$ Determine if $f$ is differentiable at the origin.

If $f$ is differentiable at the origin we have that $Df(0) = 0?$ Now from the definition we get that $$f(x)-f(0) = Df(x)(x-0) +\|x-0\|\varepsilon(x-0) = \|x\|\varepsilon(x).$$

Thus $$\frac{f(x)}{\|x\|} = \varepsilon(x).$$ However by definition $\varepsilon(x) \to 0,$ when $x \to0$, thus $f$ is differentiable at the origin.

Is my approach here right? What alternative way I could have approached this?

Looking this using the definition of partial derivatives I get that

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} = \lim_{h \to0} \frac{f(x+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = 0=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$

So the partials are both $0$ at the origin at least.

Comment: You seem to be assuming $f$ is differentiable at $0$ to begin with, which is not valid.

Comment: I see. That's why the approach fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From scratch:

$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{h_1h_2}{h_1^2+h_2^2}}.\ $ If $h_1=h_2,$ the limit is  $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, whereas if $h_1=0,$ the limit is $0$.

Comment: Where did the denominator come from for $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}$?

Comment: The denominator is $\|h\|$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $g : x \to (x, x)$ then $fog(x) = |x|$ which is not differentiable at $x=0$, so you can conclude that f is not differentiable at $0$.